# why I always get ACTION_DOWN from onTouchEvent

Tags: android, touch

I extend my class from View. and I override onTouchEvent function. But, I can get only ACTION_DOWN event. not any ACTION_UP or ACTION_MOVE. what should I do to get that events ?

I override only onTouchEvent and onDraw function. and there is only this view in application

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("event:"+event.getAction());
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Please show your code. Otherwise we can just guess around. Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Possibly you need to return `true` instead of returning the `super` event. That means that you handled that event, and thus you can receive the next one.

Answer (score 1):

At work we had a `LinearLayout` called `teaser` which was having similar issues (it's been a while). Anyway, we found that this "hack" seems to help get some extra responsiveness out of a `touch`.

```
teaser.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) v.getBackground();

        switch(motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(transition != null) transition.startTransition(250);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                loadArticle(position);
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                if(transition != null) transition.reverseTransition(0);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

// Has to be here for the touch to work properly.
teaser.setOnClickListener(null); // <-- the important part for you
```

I honestly couldn't give you any rhyme or reason to it, but hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This post may help you to see what's going on:
http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2010/07/implement-drag-and-drop-on-android.html